# How to renew CookieAuthentication expire time when some action is calling in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies

I use "Individual User Accounts" (IUA) Authentication template in my MVC 5 project. I set cookie ExpireTime 5 minutes.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ...
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        ...
```

I want to extend (renew) this cookie ExpireTime, when I call GetSomething in my Controller.

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public JsonResult GetSomething()
{
    ...
}
```

How can I extend this cookie ExpireTime in my CustomAuthorize filter?

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        ???SetNewTimeForAppAuthCookie???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookie ExpireTime extends automatically.
I used [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)] attribute in my controller class, which was cause of that problem.